# Unable to display entries: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern

I am trying to display some entries from the backend. If I pass data through Postman, the data is perfectly passed to the database. However, I'm unable to display them in the frontend. Here's my code

```
export default function EntriesDisplay() {

    const [entry,setEntry] = useState([]);
    const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);

useEffect(function() {
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/entries")
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
            setEntry(res.data)
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    }, [update])

return(
        <>
                <ul className="list-container">
                    {entry.map((data) => (
                        <EntriesCard
                            data={data}
                            handleEdit={handleEdit}
                            handleDelete={handleDelete}
                        />
                    ))}
                </ul>
```

Here's the component EntriesCard

```
function EntriesCard({data, handleEdit, handleDelete}) {
    const{_id, title, link, description} = data;

    return(
        <li key={_id}>
            <div className="title-description">
                <h3>{title}</h3>
                <h2>{link}</h2>
                <p>{description}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="button-container">
                <button className="button" name={_id} onClick={handleEdit}>
                    Edit
                </button>
                <button className="button" name={_id} onClick={handleDelete}>
                    Delete
                </button>
            </div>
        </li>
    )
}
```

Here's the backend of the code

```
app.get('/api/entries', asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const entries = await Entry.find();
    res.json(entries);
})
)
```

Comment: What is the output from `console.log(res.data);`? Is it an array? It seems the state is updated to something other than an array-like object.

Comment: How do I find its output? Should I also link the backend part?

Comment: It's right there in the `useEffect` hook, check the console log of the browser's devtools.

Comment: It's mentioning as "undefined"

Comment: Ok, try logging just `console.log(res)` then.

Comment: Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/entries', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:8000/api/entries"

Comment: Can you check the network tab for that specific request and check the "Payload", "Preview", and "Response" tabs and copy here to your post the values? Can you also share the response headers from the "Headers" tab? I'm suspecting it's just something like needing to return a `res.json()` or similar. Can add the backend code handling this request to your question?

Comment: I've added the backend in the question.

Comment: You should use `res.json()` instead of `res.data`. And note that `res.json()` will return a promise as well so you should `then` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks for confirming what the response is. It is JSON so you need to "unpack" that. Assuming the JSON `data` is still the array you need to store in state, check for ok response and return the `response.json()` Promise and continue chaining.

```
useEffect(function() {
  fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/entries")
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) throw new Error("response not ok");
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      setEntry(data);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
}, [update]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `res.json()` to parse the returned json data.

```js
useEffect(function() {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/entries")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setEntry(data)
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
}, [update])
```